# React native function auto submitting to firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

```html
function submit(email, password) { 
  FirebaseAPI.createUser(email, password)
}

export default function LoginScreen() {
  
  const [email, onChangeText] = React.useState('Enter Email');
  const [password, onChangeText2] = React.useState('Enter Password');

  const componentDidMount = () => {
    this.watchAuthState(this.props.navigation)
  }
  const watchAuthState =(navigation) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      console.log('onauthStateChanged', user)
      if (user) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
        // this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
      }
    });
  }
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.wrapper} behavior="padding">
          <View style={styles.scrollViewWrapper}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
              <Text style={styles.loginHeader}>Creat an Account </Text>
              <TextInput 
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                value={email}
              />
              <TextInput 
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText2(text)}
                value={password}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{marginTop: '5%'}}
                onPress= {(submit(email,password))}>
                <View>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity> 
            </ScrollView>
           </View>
         </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}
```

Firebase is working fine with this function but I have an issue where even if I type say john@gmail.com password sfjkskfs etc it will auto send it to firebase even before I hit the submit button.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: i think you have wrong used from onPress function. you should use onPress function to this part onPress = {() =>  this.submit(email,password)}

Comment: close it was this () => submit(email,password) thanks man!

Comment: you can submit an answer if you want so I can flag it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the `onPress` function badly. you should use just like this one :

```js
onPress = {() => this.submit(email,password)}
```